How to resolve Stored XSS and reflected XSS in visualforce page?
We are having trouble locating the problem that the Checkmarx tool reported. We have sanitized the variables in Visualforce pages using JSENCODE, HTMLENCODE, URLENCODE. We have added the escapeHTML4() in apex as well. Have we missed anything? How can We fix these problem?
Stored XSS result path 1:
<span style="float: left;padding-left:10%;" onclick="decreaseItemNo_JS('{!JSENCODE(i)}', '{!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(URLENCODE(TEXT(itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity))))}' , '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(itemIndexCount))}');" >

Reflected XSS result path 1:
guestID = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('guestId').escapeHTML4();


<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Omo__l_gl_enquiry}" onclick="window.open('{!$Site.Prefix}/apex/guestQuery?id={!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(URLENCODE(guestID)))}','_blank','height=600,width=900,left=100,top=50,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');return false;">

Reflected XSS result path 3:
<apex:repeat value="{!viewDraftReserveList}" var="v">


<td><input type="checkbox" value="{!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(v.id))}" class="slds-checkbox allRT" onclick="getIdd(this, '{!JSENCODE(HTMLENCODE(URLENCODE(v.id)))}');"/></td>


In order to answer this completely, I've made a number of assumptions:



Variable
Data Type




i
apex/iterator variable with a number


itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity
a number


itemIndexCount
a number


guest_id
alphanumeric text


v.id
a Salesforce ID



Given these conditions, we can look at how to solve these.

Stored XSS
decreaseItemNo_JS('{!JSENCODE(i)}', '{!JSENCODE(
  HTMLENCODE(
    URLENCODE(
      TEXT(itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity)
    )
  )
)}', 
'{!JSENCODE(TEXT(itemIndexCount))}');

Since we've assumed that quantity is a number, we can reduce that mess to just:
decreaseItemNo_JS('{!JSENCODE(i)}',{!itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity}, 
'{!JSENCODE(TEXT(itemIndexCount))}');

JSENCODE is never appropriate inside an HTML attribute (use JSINHTMLENCODE instead).
But again, this is a number, so there shouldn't be any way to put anything other than a number in the parameter. Similarly, using TEXT implies that itemIndexCount is a number as well, so we don't need escaping there, either.
decreaseItemNo_JS(i,
{!itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity},
{!itemIndexCount});

Note: Line breaks added for legibility.

Reflected XSS
For this case, do not use both escapeHTML4 and HTMLENCODE. Even if this were not flagged, the resulting output wouldn't be correct if any special cases existed, as they would be double-encoded (at minimum). You definitely do not need to use all three functions, as that would cause potentially triple-encoded characters. JSINHTMLENCODE or URLENCODE should be sufficient.
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Omo__l_gl_enquiry}" onclick="window.open(
'{!$Site.Prefix}/apex/guestQuery?id={!URLENCODE(guestID)}',
'_blank',
'height=600,width=900,left=100,top=50,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
);return false;">


That said, this isn't ideal programming. It can get easily confusing trying to deal with JavaScript in HTML. Your code should simply call a function, and use data attributes to make things simple. Let's take a look at the stored XSS, and see how it can be easier.
First, near the top of your page:
<script type="application/javascript">
    function decreaseItemNo_JS(event) {
        let index = event.target.dataset.index;
        let quantity = parseInt(event.target.dataset.quantity);
        let indexCount = parseInt(event.target.dataset.indexCount);
        // more logic here //
    }
</script>

And then, your markup becomes a simple:
<span style="float: left;padding-left:10%;" 
    data-index="{!i}"
    data-quantity="{!itemPriceIdVsProductToShowMap[i].quantity}"
    data-index-count="{!itemIndexCount}"
    onclick="decreaseItemNo_JS(event)" >

Note: If i, quantity, or itemIndexCount are for some reason strings, simply use HTMLENCODE. No other work needed.
Similarly, the link for the user is convoluted.
You can write:
{!URLFOR($Page.guestQuery, guestId)}

Which automatically escapes everything for you. Again, consider using an event handler to make the code easier to read:
<script type="application/javascript">
  function openWindow(event) {
    window.open(event.target.dataset.destination,
    '_blank',
'height=600,width=900,left=100,top=50,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes'
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>

<apex:commandButton 
  value="{!$Label.Omo__l_gl_enquiry}"
  html-data-destination="{!URLFOR($Page.guestQuery, guestId)}"
 onclick="openWindow(event)">

